# selecting and showing a li element of ticker bxslider on the page

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

I'm trying to write a code for selecting and showing a li element of ticker bxslider on the page. When you use the ticker bxslider, images are going and coming back from one side of the screen to the other side. I want a random image of slider that I click to show on the screen. 
Here the ticker bxslider code is

```
<div class="row sliderticker">
       <ul id="bxsliderID" class="bxslider">
         <li class="class1"></li>
         <li class="class2"></li>
         <li class="class3"></li>
         <li class="class4"></li>
         <li class="class5"></li>
         <li class="class6"></li>
         <li class="class7"></li>
         <li class="class8"></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div class="row changeable">
    <li class="changeableitem"></li>
</div>
```

I put the images to every class as background-images.And changeable div is the field to show the image I clicked.
Here the script codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 7,
  maxSlides: 8,
  slideWidth: 1200,
  slideMargin: 10,
  ticker: true,
  speed: 30000
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $( ".bxslider li" ).click(function() {
      var className = $(this).attr('class');
      $('li.changeableitem').addClass(className);
      $(this).siblings().removeClass(className);
   });
   $( "li.changeableitem" ).click(function() {
      $('li.changeableitem').hide();
   });
});
</script>
```

When I use these codes, I can show the image I clicked on the changeable div. But if i clicked the class3 li, It shows it however if then I click class1 item I cannot see it. So if I select classX li , I cannot select the li items before xth item. And I can only show li images once. If I click it second time , it does not work. Could you help me? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are you able to click higher numbers after it? i.e. can you click 1,3,5,7?

Comment: Yes I can click but after I click 7, I cannot click 6 or 2. By the way I tried jsfiddle but it does not work.

Comment: >By the way I tried jsfiddle but it does not work.  \n Do have a link to the bxSlider to show how it is working wrong?

Comment: Here the link is. I hope you can see it without a problem. https://yadi.sk/d/y8NxXTH0hwMbV. Thank you.

Comment: I think this code saves the classes and second time I try to click again it does not work. Do you know a way to reset this code second time i click         images                                                                                                   $( ".bxslider li" ).click(function() {
   var className = $(this).attr('class');
   $('li.degis').addClass(className);
});

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass(className);
```

line in your first .click() function.

Comment: thank you for your answer but even if I remove this line, I can still not return to the elements before the element I click.